# Using Yesod.Auth.Hardcoded SiteAdmin in a hamlet template

Tags: haskell, yesod

### Problem description

I've been unable to get a compiling example of using [Yesod.Auth.Hardcoded](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-6.8/yesod-auth-1.4.13.3/Yesod-Auth-Hardcoded.html). My problem is in trying to interrogate the user in a hamlet template. My `Foundation.hs` is set up as per the documentation in the link for hardcoded. My handler looks like this:

```
getHomeR :: Handler Html
getHomeR = do
    uid <- maybeAuthId
    (widget, enctype) <- generateFormPost . renderBootstrap3 BootstrapBasicForm $ blurbForm Nothing
    currentPost <- runDB $ selectFirst [] [Desc BlogId]
    currentBlurb <- runDB $ selectFirst [] [Desc BlurbId]
    defaultLayout $ do
        setTitle "My site"
        addScriptRemote "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"
        addScriptRemote "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.2.0/js/collapse.js"
        $(widgetFile "homepage")
```

My site compiles and renders happily until I try to do anything useful with the `uid` being assigned in the `do` block above.

### What I've tried

I've tried both the `$maybe` and `$case` constructs in the [hamlet documentation](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/shakespearean-templates). `$maybe` looked like this:

```
    $maybe user <- uid
       <p>There's a name
    $nothing
       <p>No name
```

This succeeded regardless of whether I logged in as the hardcoded user.

The `$case` version looked like this:

```
    $case uid
        $of Left _
            <p>There's no name
        $of Right username
            <p>It worked
```

and failed with:

```
Exception when trying to run compile-time code:
  Inside a $case there may only be $of.  Use '$of _' for a wildcard.
Code: widgetFile "homepage"
In the splice: $(widgetFile "homepage")
```

### Question(s)

Am I setting the `uid` correctly in my handler code and, if so, how should I access the hardcoded `SiteManager` in my templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As often posting the question made me think of an answer, though I'd still be grateful for any better ones. Using a combination of `$maybe` and `$case` like so:

```
    $maybe user <- uid
        $case user
            $of Left _
                <p>There's no name
            $of Right username
                <p>There might be a name of #{username}
    $nothing
       <p>No name
```

got me the correct username. Please post another answer if there is a better way.

Answer (score 1):

The AuthId type here is `Either UserId String`.

A Right value represents a "hardcoded" user which does not appear in the User table. A Left value represents a User row in the Users table.

If you want to show a name for an AuthId, you can call `getAuthEntity` which returns an `Either User SiteManager` and then process it like this:

```
getUserName :: Either User SiteManager -> String
getUserName (Left user) = ...get the name field from user...
getUserName (Right sitemgr) = manUserName sitemgr
```